# Silex não encontra as rotas

Tags: php, htaccess, rotas, php-7, silex

Tenho uma aplicação Silex 2.0 com PHP 7.0 e Apache 2.4 (na porta 8080) com a seguinte estrutura:

```
silex/
   | - vendor/
   | - web/
        | - index.php
   | - composer.json
   | - .htaccess
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7",
        "silex/silex": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
FallbackResource /silex/web/index.php
```

**web/index.php**

```
<?php

define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
chdir(APP_ROOT);

use Silex\Application;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

echo "---------------- I am here! -----------------";

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    echo 'inside get';
   return $app->json(['Hello World!']);
});

$app->run();
```

**E o problema é esse:**

[image: Silex Error -]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que a sua rota é **/** e você está acessando **/silex/** no nevegador.

Você tem pelo menos três soluções para resolver este problema.

**Solução 1**

Como você está usando o servidor Apache, você pode criar um VirtualHost para apontar diretamente para o diretório do seu projeto.

Por exemplo, você cria um VirtualHost com o nome http://minhaaplicacao.local/ e ele irá apontar direto para a pasta *web* do seu projeto.

Documentação sobre Virtual Host (em inglês): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

**Solução 2**

Em vez de usar o Apache, use o servidor embutido do PHP via terminal.

Exemplo:

```
cd /home/pasta-do-seu-projeto
php -S localhost:8000 -t web/
```

Dessa forma o seu projeto estará acessível no endereço http://localhost:8000/

Documentação sobre o servidor embutido do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php

**Solução 3**

Esta é a solução menos recomendada, mas se for o caso você pode inserir o caminho */silex/* direto na sua rota:

```
$app->get('/silex/', function() use ($app) {
    echo 'inside get';
   return $app->json(['Hello World!']);
});
```

Comment: Vlw cara! TEstei a solução 2 e 3, pra ver se rolava, ambas corretas. A solução 1 preferi nem testar, porquê não quero ficar criando um VirtualHost para cada projeto que por ventura venha a criar. Utilizarei a Solução 2, obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! :D